# ASP.NET Core apps developed in Visual Basic.NET (VB.NET), is it possible? There is no Templates in VS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

There is no support for Razor pages in VB.NET.
There is no templates for ASP.NET CORE in Visual Studio 2019 for VB.NET.

But **I love this language**.

How can I develop an ASP.NET Core (3.0 or greater) website or app in VB.NET?

It seems **that is impossible** at this time to develop Web applications in VB.NET using .NET Core.

Comment: The question is way too broad for SO. Using particular rendering engine was never requirement for ASP.Net MVC - as long as your controllers return actions that render what you need it should be fine. You may need to implement your own actions to render HTML... or look around to see if there is alternative rendering engine you like...

Comment: My question is about .NET Core, there is no templates in Visual Studio for develop ASP.NET CORE.

Answer (score 3):

You can put everything, except the Razor/Blazor pages itself and the Program.cs a library project.

Here is an example of what I do in a Controllers project. 
At first, there is a base class, I use for all/most of my controllers. If required, there are variations of the constructor. Depending on which DI objects are used by the derived class. 
As you can see, it is nothing different from a implementation in C#. 
@Riaan: Even the Identity Framework works just as in C#. I added an example with authorization.

```
Public MustInherit Class ControllerBase
    Inherits Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase

    Private ReadOnly _configuration As IConfiguration
    Protected ReadOnly Property Configuration As IConfiguration
        Get
            Return _configuration
        End Get
    End Property

    Private ReadOnly _logger As ILogger(Of Object)
    Protected ReadOnly Property Logger As ILogger(Of Object)
        Get
            Return _logger
        End Get
    End Property

    Private ReadOnly _signInManager As SignInManager(Of Identity.MyProjectIdentity)
    Protected ReadOnly Property SignInManager As SignInManager(Of Identity.MyProjectIdentity)
        Get
            Return _signInManager
        End Get
    End Property

    Private ReadOnly _userManager As UserManager(Of Identity.MyProjectIdentity)
    Protected ReadOnly Property UserManager As UserManager(Of Identity.MyProjectIdentity)
        Get
            Return _userManager
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal configuration As IConfiguration,
                   ByVal logger As ILogger(Of Object),
                   ByVal signInManager As SignInManager(Of Identity.MyProjectIdentity),
                   ByVal userManager As UserManager(Of Identity.MyProjectIdentity))

        _configuration = configuration
        _logger = logger
        _signInManager = signInManager
        _userManager = userManager

    End Sub

End Class


<Controller()>
<Route("Media")>
Public Class MediaController
    Inherits MyProject.Controllers.ControllerBase

    Private ReadOnly _mediaService As MediaService
    Protected ReadOnly Property MediaService As MediaService
        Get
            Return _mediaService
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal configuration As IConfiguration,
                   ByVal signInManager As SignInManager(Of Identity.MyProjectIdentity),
                   ByVal userManager As UserManager(Of Identity.MyProjectIdentity),
                   ByVal logger As ILogger(Of MediaController),
                   ByVal mediaService As MediaService)
        MyBase.New(configuration, logger, signInManager, userManager)

        _mediaService = mediaService

    End Sub            


    <HttpGet("Placeholder/{width:int}/{height:int}")>
    Public Function Placeholder(ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer) As IActionResult

        Try

            Dim resultImage = Imaging.Placeholder.GetPlaceholderImage(300, 300)

            Dim ms = New IO.MemoryStream()
            resultImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png)
            ms.Position = 0

            Return File(ms, "image/png", $"Placeholder_{width}x{height}.png")

        Catch ex As Exception

            Return StatusCode(500)

        End Try

    End Function


 <Authorize()>
    <HttpGet("AuthenticatorQRCode/{userName}/{sharedKey}")>
    Public Async Function AuthenticatorQRCode(ByVal userName As String, ByVal sharedKey As String) As Task(Of IActionResult)

        Try

            Dim user = Await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(Me.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value)

            If user.UserName <> userName Then
                Return StatusCode(403)
            End If

            Dim domain As String = Configuration.GetSection("Cookies").GetValue(Of String)("Domain")
            Dim qrCodeDataString As String = $"otpauth://totp/{domain}:{userName}?secret={sharedKey}&issuer={domain}&digits=6"

            Dim qrImage = Imaging.QRCode.GetQRCode(qrCodeDataString)

            Dim ms = New System.IO.MemoryStream()
            qrImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png)
            ms.Position = 0

            Return File(ms, "image/png", "QRCode.png")

        Catch ex As Exception

            Return StatusCode(500)

        End Try

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Yes, this is a VB.NET Controller Class from a ASP.NET Core 3.1 project.

Comment: I am just wondering if you got the login (user credentials) via a rest API to work? and if you did if you would be willing to share and example?

Comment: @Riaan: Of course. I extended the example a little with a authorized controller action.

Comment: thank you for the update. this is helpful, especially the identity framework